# Python: creating DSL

Tags: python, dsl, lark-parser

I need to solve some specialized task, connecting with creating a DSL to specific purposes. 
But I have no experience with it and after some research I choose python `Lark`.
I need to realize some like

```
age1 = 20, age2 = 35; If age1 more than age2, than do_smth
```

And I need to realize condition in this DSL.
I saw a lot of docs, connecting with it, but there is only declare variables and that's all.
Can you share some resources to get more about this library

Comment: Did you check already the [docs](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/tree/master/docs)? Recently a cheatsheet has been added. Also, please post what you've tried so far in the form of a mcve... otherwise you won't get many help from Stackoverflow with this type of generic questions